# How to calculate the size of file generated using node js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I created a csv file using node js and uploaded that to S3 bucket. Is there a way to calculate the size of the file generate.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this by below steps**

```
const fs = require('fs');  
const {size} = fs.statSync('path/to/file');
```